# What does Kili say to Tauriel in dwarvish when he gives her the moon rune, in The Battle of The Five Armies?

Tags: the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium

Can anyone find the meaning of what Kili says to Tauriel when he gives her the moon rune in The Battle of the Five Armies, in both English and Dwarvish?

The scene right after they arrive on the shores, after leaving Lake Town, when Kili confesses his feelings, he says something to Tauriel in Dwarvish and I wanted the spelling of the saying in Dwarvish and in English and the meaning if anyone would be able to find out.

Comment: It's dwarvish for "Peter Jackson want more cash."

Comment: @MishaRosnach - I though it was dwarvish for "how can we shoehorn a female character into this film?"

Comment: @Richard From a producer's viewpoint, those are the same thing. "There are no prominent women in our movie. Therefore, women won't want to see our movie, because they only like girl stuff. If we awkwardly force a female character into the story, her mere presence will draw women to the theaters, where they will give us money. Oh, and give her a love triangle, because everybody likes those."

Comment: @KSmart Hey don't bring all that "producers viewpoint" stuff into this. Richard and I were discussing Dwarvish. This is about language.  You see, dwarves are rude, so "shoehorn" and "want" are essentially the same word. And male dwarves love gold and ladies equally, so "cash" and "female character" are often the same word too. Those are very commonly confused.

Comment: @MishaRosnach How do the dwarves know who Peter Jackson is? Are they *Braindead* fans?

Comment: Even the friendship of Legolas and Gimli was deemed unusual because the two races were not exactly friendly for close to 6500 years! I was rolling my eyes so hard -- yeah, two of them will fall in love at practically first sight.

Answer (score 21):

Let me borrow [from *The Dwarrow Scholar*](https://dwarrowscholar.wordpress.com/2014/12/11/tbotfa-spoiler-love-is-all-you-need/):

> Kíli says to Tauriel “amrâlimê” […]
>
> I believe the word consists of three parts “amrâl”, “im” and “ê”
>
> “amrâl” – means “love”. It used the abstract construction aCCâC as seen in the Tolkien original khuzdul words such as “aglâb”. The radicals in amrâl, MRL are faintly reminiscent of the Quenya “melmë” (love) and “mírima” (very lovely), and of the Sindarin “meleth” (love), while also hinting at the latin “amorem” (love).
>
> “im” – […] it seems clear this is a genitive marker, indicating “of”.
>
> “ê” – is the first person possessive pronoun “my”, also use for “me”.
>
> Putting all of this together we get “love-of-me”
>
> So, as a result we get: “**My Love**”

Answer (score 1):

From several D.Salo articles on his site midgardsmal.com (The serendipity of error, Paradixis):
if m-r-l = "love" maybe from Primitive Elvish/Valarin root MER- "wish, desire, want" from The Etymologies,

or metathesis m-l-r=m-r-l from root MEL- love

a12a3i - imperfect 1 person (I love)

mê - pronoun 3 person singular familiar you
(early in pronouns paradigm it was 1 person plural "we")

Summary: I love (desire?) you.

It could be recognized from context.

But say it to Elven maiden in Dwarvish (not Elvish or Common) - it is not clever thing

Comment: “3 person singular familiar you” does not make any sense. ‘You’ is second person; was that what you meant?

Answer (score -2):

Amralime. Considering Tauriel's reaction to him saying it, and the fact that he gave her his moonrune, I'm pretty sure it means "I love you", "My love", or "Beloved".

Comment: Can you give evidence?